# Find the same pattern in two files python

Tags: python

Im trying to find a word that is in a file and search for that word in two different files 
- to search that word in the first file and if the word is found the the line is printed in a new file 
- to search for the same word in a second file and if the word is found to print the line found in the second file in the same output file after the line found in the first file and separated with a *tabulation.*

this is the script that i wrote :

```
for line in first_file:
   for line2 in second_file:
      for word in keywords:
       if re.match (r"\b"+word+r"\b" , line):
          result = (line.strip()+'\t'+line2.strip())
          print (result, file = new_file)
```

but the result that i get is always an empty file.

```
This is an example of the first file : 
contig-39000000 1211    11.3902
contig-44000000 6128    17.8944
contig-91000000 2180    14.2197

this is an example of the second file 
contig-316000330    out.18
contig-39000000 out.25
```

...

and this is an example of the search file

```
contig-39000000
contig-289000379
contig-300000489
contig-310000168
contig-310000172
contig-320000463
contig-324000213
contig-327000055
contig-341000436
contig-342000384
....
```

The expected result would look like :

```
contig-39000000 1211    11.3902   out.25
```

Thank you

Comment: Please provide sample snippets of both input files...

Comment: Please add those to the question as an edit. Which phrase do you want to look for? The whole line or just a specific expression?

Comment: My guess: `second_file` is a `file` object, i.e. an iterator, and after the first word from the first file, that iterator is exhausted, so no other words can be found.

Comment: So there are 3 files here, correct? First, second, and search?

Comment: yes there would be 3 files

Comment: @cricket_007: Two input files and an output file (as far as I understood).

Comment: And you also want to merge the lines with the same `contig-` string?

Comment: exactly i woul like to search for the same pattern in two different files
and if the pattern is found in the first file and the second (which is the case)
to write in the same output file the line from the first file and after it the line from the second file seperated by a tabulation

Comment: @MondherKHEDIRI: So based on which criterion did you match the lines in your example since the 'IDs' (`contig-xyz`) do not seem to be equal. How long are those files? Are you allowed to use additional modules?

Comment: it is just an example i took the head of ech file so it doesn't really match but in the real case it does

Comment: What about additional modules handling the data as csv-like data?

Comment: I imagine SQLite with a JOIN on the first columns should be all you really need here. The triple-nested for loop will be really slow for large files.

Comment: Is the search key always the first field in the line?

Comment: Besides SQLite I think about doing something with two pandas DataFrames...

Comment: if it would work i will try it but i don't have any idea how to do that in the csv mode

Comment: In this case the search key is always in the first coloumn

Comment: Are all three files always in sorted ascending order? And are the keys unique in each file?

Comment: The key is unique in each file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah, pandas was much easier than SQLite.

```
import pandas as pd

# change sep to use '\t' if those files actually are tab-delimited 
df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.txt', sep=r'\s+', header=None)
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.txt', sep=r'\s+', header=None)

result = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=0)
result.to_csv('output.txt', sep='\t', header=False, index=False)
```

---

Contents of `file1.txt`

```
contig-39000000 1211    11.3902
contig-44000000 6128    17.8944
contig-91000000 2180    14.2197
```

Contents of `file2.txt`

```
contig-39000000     out.13
contig-316000330    out.18
contig-316000341    out.25
```

Contents of `output.txt`

```
contig-39000000 1211    11.3902 out.13
```

Comment: In contrast to [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34276645/3991125) the solution provided here produces nicer output since `merge()` provides exactly what we want to. No empty `NaN` cells...

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this is to put the first two files into dictionaries. We can then loop through the search document and see if the entry is a key in our first dictionary. If it is, we retrieve the value (the original line) and search for it in the second. If it is also in the second, we append the value to our text and then write it out to the file.

```
first_dict = {line.split()[0]: line for line in first_file}
second_dict = {line.split()[0]: line.split()[1] for line in second_file}

for search in search_file:
    if search in first_dict:
        out_text = first_dict[search]

        if search in second_dict:
            out_text = out_text + "\t" + second_dict[search]

        new_file.write(out_text)
```

Comment: I tried using dictionary with the upper code but the result that i got is :
    IndexError: list index out of range
i guess because the entry elements are so big

Comment: That could be caused by a line in the second file not having a space in it. Do you know if that ever happens?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [Pandas DataFrames](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) which are really useful in order to handle bigger data.

My approach is as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

import pandas as pd

# read both input files
df1 = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', delim_whitespace=True, names=['A', 'B'], index_col=0)
df2 = pd.read_csv('file2.csv', delim_whitespace=True, names=['C'], index_col=0)

# concat the DataFrames read generated from the read data on same index
df3 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)

# print all DataFrames in order to double-check
print(df1)
print(df2)
print(df3)

# write concated DataFrame to output.csv
df3.to_csv('output.csv', header=False, sep='\t')
```

This snippet will consume two input files and produce an output file like this:

output.csv:

```
contig-316000330            out.18
contig-39000000 1211.0  11.3902 out.25
contig-44000000 6128.0  17.8944 
contig-91000000 2180.0  14.2197
```

---

file1.csv (input file):

```
contig-39000000 1211    11.3902
contig-44000000 6128    17.8944
contig-91000000 2180    14.2197
```

---

file2.csv (input file):

```
contig-316000330    out.18
contig-39000000 out.25
```

Comment: Just barely beat you to an answer ;)

Comment: Same idea but slightly different approach. Nice to see that other people have quite similar ideas to mine. Great to learn from each other.

Comment: I think you forgot OP wanted output to be tab-delimited, though.

Comment: Just fixed that. Thanks for this hint.